# How to find out a number after a phrase in a text file using php

Tags: php, file, edit, phrase

I have made a chatroom with php and I would like to be able to add the ability to comment on a post, and to do this,  I need to be able to find out a the number after a phrase in php.

The phrase will always be "this is post number: " but the number changes based on what post number the post you are looking at is.

[The website is linked here](http://www.everyone.x10host.com)

Below, I have the code that inserts the formatted user input into a .txt file:

```
 //increases the post number by 1
      $post_num = file_get_contents("post_num.txt");
      $post_num ++;
      file_put_contents("post_num.txt", $post_num);
 //writes message to file
      file_put_contents('posts.txt', "<div class='post'><div class='title'><b>" . $title . "</b></div>" . $postimg . "<div class='message'>" . showBBcodes($message) . "</div><div class='footer'>Posted By: " . $username . "<br> This is post number: " . $post_num . "</div><form action='finish_comment.php' method='post'><input placeholder='comment' name='comment'><input type='submit' value='comment'></form></div><br> \n", FILE_APPEND);
 //redirects the user back to posts.php
      echo "<script>location.href = 'posts.php'</script>";
```

The phrase with the post number is in the piece of code that reads:

```
<div class='footer'>Posted By: " . $username . "<br> This is post number: " . $post_num . "</div>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a database?

Comment: Anyway, you can use a regular expression: `This is post number: (\d+)`

Comment: I am currently in the process of learning SQL but it can be hard with a free host.

Comment: So I could find the value of \d+ after the phrase and put it into a variable for usage correct?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. That's what capture groups are for. You can also use a positive lookbehind. Read a regexp tutorial.

Comment: You should use DOMDdocument or at least include the <br> tag in your regular expression imagine  this conversation in the chat: -Bob: which post? Alice: This is post number: 5 darling .

Comment: this might be off topic, but how do I move something to a discussion if the link has dissapeared?

Comment: SQL might seem hard in the beginning, but it will be a lot easier than using a text file in the long run.